Uploads folder in wwwroot doesn't have access to delete a file by the app
I have an Uploads folder in an App Service and uploading is successful.
However, when the app tries to delete the uploaded files, it encounters the error:

System.IO.IOException: Invalid access to memory location. : 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\sample\uploads\MyFile.txt'

I see the structure to be: myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/wwwroot/sample/uploads/MyFile.txt
private readonly string myUploadFolderPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", configuration["mySettings:UploadsFolderPath"]);

public bool RemoveUploadedFiles() {
    if (Directory.Exists(myUploadFolderPath)) {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(myUploadFolderPath);

        foreach (string file in files) {
            File.Delete(file);
        }   
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

we have a pipeline in Azure Devops to deploy, what deployment settings to be used for write permission to be enabled.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    #zipAfterPublish: true # commented    

# this code takes all the files in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and uploads them as an artifact of your build.

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ZOMWE(3e562eb-g31f-4241-579f-2c3e460354a1)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    appName: 'azvcx'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'  # added
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'


Please share more details.

Please share the code that you've tried.

Are you sure the path is correct?

@SirraSneha updated the post, thank you.

what is the framework of your app (node.js,react, asp.net)

I noticed that the path includes two wwwroot directories (C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\sample\uploads\MyFile.txt).
Could you double-check the file structure on the App Service?

@SirraSneha I see that in the structure too:  myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/wwwroot/sample/uploads/MyFile.txt

ok will try and let you know

@SirraSneha it is .net blazor app

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I created a sample Blazor application, and I can successfully upload and delete the file from the folder without any issues.
Make sure you add correct upload path in your appsettings.json file.
appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "UploadFolderPath": "sample/uploads" 
}

I used asynchronous deletion as this prevents the blocking and makes the application more responsive.
My complete FileService.cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FileUploadApp.Services
{
    public class FileService
    {
        private readonly string _uploadFolderPath;
        private readonly ILogger<FileService> _logger;

        public FileService(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<FileService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger)); 
        
            var uploadFolderPathConfig = configuration["UploadFolderPath"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadFolderPathConfig))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uploadFolderPathConfig), "Upload folder path cannot be null or empty.");
            }

            _uploadFolderPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", uploadFolderPathConfig);

            _logger.LogInformation($"Upload folder path: {_uploadFolderPath}");

            if (!Directory.Exists(_uploadFolderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_uploadFolderPath);
                _logger.LogInformation("Created upload folder.");
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> UploadFile(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_uploadFolderPath))
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Upload folder path is null or empty.");
                    return false;
                }

                var filePath = Path.Combine(_uploadFolderPath, fileName);
                _logger.LogInformation($"Uploading file to {filePath}");

                using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(file);
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("File uploaded successfully.");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error uploading file: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> RemoveUploadedFiles()
        {
            try
            {
 
                if (Directory.Exists(_uploadFolderPath))
                {
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(_uploadFolderPath);
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() => File.Delete(file));  
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error deleting files: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

Filedelete.razor:
@page "/file-delete"
@using FileUploadApp.Services
@inject FileService FileService

<h3>Delete Uploaded Files</h3>

<button @onclick="DeleteFiles">Delete All Files</button>
<p>@statusMessage</p>

@code {
    private string statusMessage;

    private async Task DeleteFiles()
    {
        var success = await FileService.RemoveUploadedFiles();

        statusMessage = success ? "All files deleted successfully!" : "Failed to delete files.";
    }
}

Output after deployment:

After successfully uploading the file, we can view the file in kudu by navigating to Site -> wwwroot - > wwwroot ->  sample -> uploads.


Here I've successfully deleted the files and below you can see there are no files in my kudu console.


Thanks a lot.
we have a pipeline to deploy, could you tell what deployment settings to be used for write permission to be enabled.

If you're deploying via azure pipielines, ensure the task used in your pipeline has the proper settings.                                                                                                                      set    additionalArguments: '-property:WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0'

Run From Package makes the file system read-only, set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0 to disable it and enable write access

I've updated my question with pipeline code

we can add this WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0 in your pipeline or directly in environment variable of your azure web app. Try adding like this and let me know if it's working or not.

I've added that however I see that the app deployment files are not found in kudu. There is some issue with the pipeline code that aligns with WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
